# How to properly use nodejs to post multiple records in a nested array of arrays into a mysql table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, reactjs, post

I am attempting to send an array of objects to a node server on https that will post them to a mysql table, the reason being that I need to insert multiple rows. From what I have read I am supposed to use a nested array. But I am unsure how to process once it's sent to the node server. Below is what I am working with:

**Array**

```
menuItems: [
                {
                    "id": 1234,
                    "item_name": 'meal',
                    "price": 6
                },
                {
                    "id": 1235,
                    "item_name": 'drink',
                    "price": 6
                }
            ],
```

**Send Function**

```
 sendMenuItems = (id, item_name, price) => {

        //translate array of objects to array of arrays
        const output = this.state.menuItems.map(function(obj) {
            return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
              return obj[key];
            });
          });

        fetch(
         //HOW DO I FIT OUTPUT INTO MY POST REQUEST?
        `${x}/addMenuItem?id=${id}&item_name=${item_name&price=${price}`,
        { method: "POST" }
        ).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

**Node Server**

```
app.post('/addMenuItem',  cors(), (req, res) => {
    
      var values = {
        id: req.query.id,
        item_name: req.query.item_name,
        price: req.query.price
       }

       let sql = 'INSERT INTO db.menu(id,item_name,price) VALUES ?';

       // now the createStudent is an object you can use in your database insert logic.
       pool.query(sql, values, function (err, results) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.send(err)
            
        } else {
           
            return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: 'ok', status: HttpStatus.OK })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems like the `output` variable is just being thrown away and not sent to the server. You didn't include it in the POST request. It's up to you how to define the addMenuItem API, but one option is making the menu items be the request body. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body